# Dart null safety command

Tags: flutter, dart

When I try to migrate my project to null safety with dart migrate command I get this error
Error: Error when reading 'migrate': No such file or directory

Also I try dart pub outdated --mode=null-safety and I get this error

Error: Error when reading 'pub': No such file or directory

What is this ?

Comment: It sounds like you're running an old version of Dart.  When you run `dart --version`, what does it say?  Did you install the Dart 2.12 SDK?

Answer (score 1):

I had this issue and just figured it out. It turns out that I already had Dart installed but then Flutter also includes Dart in its SDK. I had to update my path so that the Flutter version of Dart was listed first: https://flutter.dev/docs/get-started/install/macos#update-your-path